# How do I bind a checkbox to a boolean in Play! framework

Tags: java, binding, playframework

An app I'm working on using the Play! Framework has an object called gift with a boolean property, called Taken.  How do I show the state of this value as a checkbox on my view?  I've tried :-

```
<input id="gift_Taken" class="" type="checkbox" name="gift.Taken" value="true"  />
<input type="hidden" name="gift.Taken" value="false" />
```

based on examples I've seen from the autogenerated CRUD forms, but the checkbox is not checked when the property is True, which is what I'm aiming for.

Anyone know the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Just set `value='true'` on checkbox and in your method signature add a parameter `boolean taken` it'll do the binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set the `checked` value against the checkbox, if the value is true.

for example (assuming the object sent in from the view is called `gift`, and the boolean value is called `Taken`.

```
<input id="gift_Taken" type="checkbox" name="gift.Taken" ${gift.Taken ? 'checked':''}  />
```

Comment: Perfect - I love ternary operators ;-)  Side note, gonna go get that book of yours

Comment: The ternary operator is even more powerful in Groovy. Checkout the elvis operator http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator%28%3F%3A%29

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I tried `<input type="checkbox" ${true ? 'checked' : ''} />` so this should have it checked all the time. But it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: @DaoLam, probably too late here, but Play 2.0 requires using something like `@if(gift.Taken) { "checked" }`. I suspect that this answer is old and applies to a version that did not use `@` to have code in templates.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is actually not 100% correct as it doesn't handle the "unchecked" case. To handle both cases you need a hidden field:

```
<input id="gift_Taken" type="checkbox" name="gift.Taken" ${gift.Taken ? 'checked':''}  />
<input type="hidden" name="gift.Taken" value="false" />
```

Note that the placement seems to be important, so the hidden field must be after the checkbox.

Writing a custom template tag for this, makes it easy not to forget the hidden input (put this into views/tags/checkbox.html):

```
<input id="${_id}" type="checkbox" name="${_name}" value="true" #{if _checked} checked="checked" #{/if}>
<input type="hidden" name="${_name}" value="false">
```

Then call this template like this:

```
#{checkbox id:'gift_Taken', name: 'gift.Taken', checked: gift.Taken /}
```

See also the related discussion on the play framework list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/HygQuYF3a8E

Comment: Though not ideal, another solution is if a default value of false is used in the model, the absence of a submitted checkbox value will implicitly be interpreted as false. Red flags all over, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for the ordering hint (in e.g. php one uses the same solution, but the hidden field is placed before the checkbox)!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use javascript, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ":checkbox" ).each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        if(typeof(name) != "undefined") {
            var checkboxString = "";
            checkboxString = '<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" name="'+ name +'" value="false" />'
            $(this).after(checkboxString);
        }
    });
});
```