# Play Framework 2.3.x mapping a checkbox to a boolean field

Tags: forms, checkbox, playframework, playframework-2.3

Using Java Play Framework 2.3.7, I have a custom view template for a form with a text field and a select dropdown. [This is how I was able to get my custom view to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28537746/1092403). Now, I need to add a checkbox to this view template. I am having trouble getting the checkbox to map properly to a `boolean` attribute. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204708/how-do-i-bind-a-checkbox-to-a-boolean-in-play-framework) but it seems to be for an older version of Play, so it isn't helpful to me.

I have a class `CSVData` which contains a list of type `CSVField`. Here are the attributes for these classes:

```
public class CSVData{

    public Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String dataFilePath;
    private List<CSVField> fields;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;


    // rest of class... }
```

and

```
public class CSVField {

    public Long id;
    public CSVData owner;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private boolean uniqueField;

...}
```

In my controller I have this

```
Form<CSVData> formData = Form.form(CSVData.class).bindFromRequest();
```

In my view template I have this (most bootstrap styling removed for brevity):

```
@helper.repeat(csvForm("fields"), min=1) { csvField =>
    @fieldGroup(csvField, optionMap = myTypes)
}
```

Where `@fieldGroup` is the following:

```
@fieldGroup(csvField: Field, optionMap: List[String]) = {
<div class="multi-field">
    <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="@csvField("name").name"
        value="@csvField("name").value.getOrElse("")"/>

    <select
        class="form-control"
        id="select-type"
        name="@csvField("type").name"
        >
        <option class="blank" value="">Select type</option>
        @for((optionName) <- optionMap) {
            <option id="@optionName" value="@optionName" @if(csvField("type").value.equals(Some(optionName))) {selected} >
                    @optionName
            </option>
        }
    </select>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
            name="@csvField("uniqueField").name"
            value=@csvField("uniqueField").value.getOrElse(true)> Unique
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
}
```

This ends up looking like [image: fieldGroup]

However, when I fill in my form and submit it, the true/false value is not saved properly  <strike>I get a Persistence Exception</strike> . I think the issue is with the `value=@csvField("unique").value.getOrElse(true)` portion of the checkbox. **How can I set up the checkbox value properly so it maps to my boolean attribute?**

<strike>PS - [Here is the stacktrace of the exception that I am seeing](http://pastebin.com/FwNSABBr)</strike>

EDIT - updated my models above

EDIT2 - the exception is fixed

Comment: __Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "csvdata_seq" does not exist__ have you got ID field added for this model?

Comment: Yes, both of my models have `id`s. I forgot to add that in my question originally, see my edit above

Comment: How about `@Id` annotation?

Comment: Yes, both have `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`. Here is my `conf/evolutions.default/1.sql` file http://pastebin.com/sj8ErUnG

Comment: The exception I was getting was because I used the name `unique` to name an attribute. When Ebean translated this to SQL, it became `unique              boolean` and "unique" is a keyword in SQL which created problems. I've renamed it to `uniqueField` and now the exception went away.